# write a function that takes 'a'as a parameter and returns 1 if 'a' is upper triangular matrix , 0 otherwise

Tags: c

as i am new to programing , i am learning functions now , for the above question i tried a code but its not working . I am unabel to find whats wrong in this code .So please help me to correct this code.in the output it should print 1 if the matrix is upper triangular matrix otherwise print 0 .

```
#include<stdio.h>
int checkUTM(int a[100][100])
{
int i,j,n,flag=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  if(a[i][j]!=0)
  flag=0;
  else flag=1;
  return flag;
  }
int main()
{
int i,j,n,a[n][n];
scanf("%d",&n);
printf(" columns=rows=%d",n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
 for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
  printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  }
printf("%d",checkUTM(a));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The effect of your `for` loops is the same as if you had no loops and only `if(a[n-1][n-1]!=0) flag=0; else flag=1;` because only the last time through the loops will remain for the `return`

Comment: my compiler is not showing any errors for this code, and sorry that i dont know how to turn on compiler warning .

Comment: FYI, the `n` in main is not the same as the `n` in checkUTM. The `n` in checkUTM is not initialized, so it will contain some garbage value, which is sure to cause Undefined Behavior. Perhaps you want to pass `n` as a parameter from main? Also, you use `n` (in main) as the array dimension before it is defined. You probably want to move the `int a[n][n];` down one line to AFTER the scanf.

Comment: Just search on the web, it should be easy to find out how to enable warnings. Also, format your code consistently. Most IDEs can do it automatically for you. Also, read [ask], because "its not working" is not a good problem description.

Comment: In `main`, define `int a[n][n];` after the `scanf` that reads `n`. Also change `int checkUTM(int a[100][100])` to `int checkUTM(int n, int a[n][n])` and change the function call to `checkUTM(n, a)`.

Comment: but it is returning 0 when i gives the  input of an upper triangular matrix rather it should return 1 ,what could be the reason for this

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set n to be anything in the checkUTM function.
(also you can set flag = 1 and just erase the 'else flag = 1;' part)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).